# Shiny: Passing on text with a space to chart does not work, but it works without a space

Tags: r, string, shiny, spaces

My Shiny script gets input from a drop down list. Based on this, I set (on the server side) a specific string (in a reactive) that should be displayed in the chart (for example as x axis title). This works only if the string contains no spaces, but no string is shown in the chart if contains spaces.

How can I get it to accept any string?

Here's my code (I modified one of the example from the Shiny tutorial to keep it as simple as possible):

```
# server.r
# Here the string is set depending on what was chosen by the user
shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
label1_new <- reactive({
if (input$variable1=="pp_pmw") {label1_new <- "PP pmw"}
if (input$variable1=="perc_pp*100") {label1_new <- "PP percent"}
if (input$variable1=="formality") {label1_new <- "Formality"}
})

label1_new2 <- renderText({label1_new()})

output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
x    <- faithful[, 2]  # Old Faithful Geyser data
bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$bins + 1)

# draw the histogram with the specified number of bins
# xlabel1_new2() contains the string from above
hist(x, breaks = bins, col = 'darkgray', border = 'white', xlab=label1_new2())
})

})


# ui.r
library(shiny)


shinyUI(fluidPage(

# Application title
titlePanel("Hello Shiny!"),

# Sidebar with a slider input for the number of bins
sidebarLayout(
sidebarPanel(
  selectInput("variable1", "Circle size:",
            list("PP pmw" = "pp_pmw", 
                 "PP percent" = "perc_pp*100", 
                 "Formality" = "formality")),

  sliderInput("bins",
              "Number of bins:",
              min = 1,
              max = 50,
              value = 30)
),

# Show a plot of the generated distribution
mainPanel(
  plotOutput("distPlot")
)
)
))
```

Comment: none of the choices work for me with this example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

renderText is for use with ui.r, not for creating strings to be used in server.r

```
# server.r
# Here the string is set depending on what was chosen by the user
shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
label1_new <- reactive({
  if (input$variable1=="pp_pmw") return("PP pmw")
  if (input$variable1=="perc_pp*100") return("PP percent")
  if (input$variable1=="formality") return("Formality")
})


output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
  x    <- as.numeric(unlist(faithful[, 2]))  # Old Faithful Geyser data
  bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$bins + 1)

  # draw the histogram with the specified number of bins
  hist(x, breaks = bins, col = 'darkgray', border = 'white', xlab=label1_new())
})

})
```

(same ui.r)

Comment: Thank you so much! What helped was to add 'server' to 'shinyServer(function(input, output)' and use 'return' in the function ('renderText' might be superfluous, as you say, but I don't think it was the source of the error).

Comment: whoops, I thought you just missed shinyServer() in the example because you didn't copy the whole thing. So I edited your post. it was missing in the original program? you had the closing braces already though...
Also renderText was surely the source of your error. Your function has the same effect as the returns but its just a little obfuscated in your case because its returning the value of the side effect of an assignment, rather than returning it directly. Same thing.
Check out the code behind renderText. Its not returning a string, which is what you need.

Comment: You're right, shinyServer() was missing in the code I originally posted. But that was just because I missed it when copying the code, on my computer I actually had 'shinyServer(function(input, output)'.